# Difference between 月 and 月份 for the noun "A month"

Tags: grammar

So, I'm trying to figure out what is a better way to simply translate "An important month". For example if I wanted to talk about the month of Ramadan I originally said

"斋月是穆斯林非常重要的一个月“ 
but a friend (Sean C.) corrected me to say 
斋月是穆斯林非常重要的一个月份“ 
Could someone explain this difference? Does 月 sound incorrect in this instance?  Is there a simple way to think about the two as nouns?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both `重要的月份` and `重要的一個月` works fine for translating "an important month". But `重要的月` minus the unit of measurement (份/一個) sounds more like you're speaking of the Moon.

The difference between 月 and 月份 is that the latter is specifying *a month of the year*, while the former is more ambiguous: it could refer to the moon, or *a month's time*. Thus 月份 could be used standalone but you would normally prefix 一個 to 月, as you did.

It is perfectly okay to say `斋月是伊斯兰最重要的一个月`.

---

I suspect the reason your friend corrected you was because the topic was [Ramadan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramadan).

Traditionally (in some parts), 九月 means September in the *[Gregorian calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar)*, while 九月份 refers to the ninth month of the *[traditional lunisolar Han Calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_calendar#Modern_Han_Calendar)*. By extension, he might have felt the ninth month of the *[Islamic Hijri Calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_calendar)* (which is what Ramadan is) should also be a 月份.

This isn't a matter of grammar, but rather a customary usage.

Comment: 月 and 月份 have nothing to do with Gregorian calendar or Han Calendar.

Comment: @HenryHO As usual with your habitually unfounded criticisms of my answers, you're again wrong. I am not claiming that 月/月份 has to do with the calendar type; **I'm offering a possible explanation for why Stephen's friend falsely "corrected" him.** I explained the actual difference in the first half of my answer.

Comment: Being once or twice isn't "habitual".  :)  And I am eager to see your "founded source" of "九月份 refers to the ninth month of the traditional lunisolar Han Calendar".

Comment: @HenryHO And I am eager to see you acquire reading comprehension skills. But I'm not holding my breath.

Comment: Yup, I found someone suddenly casting uncommented downvotes to my answers in other questions.  Just take your time.  ^__^

Comment: @HenryHO No comments is just as well, since you are incapable of understanding what you read, as your ridiculous attacks here demonstrate.

Comment: would you mind referring me to some sources supporting your statement "九月份 refers to the ninth month of the traditional lunisolar Han Calendar" ?   I would like to know which parts of China/other countries have this tradition.

Comment: @HenryHO Or you could google it: http://iask.sina.com.cn/b/1482342.html - but clearly you don't even understand what that statement means anyway, so whats the use?

Comment: Oh my god, do you realize that you are saying the opposite to the Sina answer?  :P  (Not to mention that the Sina answer is also an unfounded claim.)

Comment: @HenryHO My bad, I don't have the Baidu link I used at home so I grabbed the top google result. But you whining about "unfounded claim" confirms my last comment. Obviously you **still** fail at realising the point is how some people think its different.

Answer (score 2):

`月` refers to the duration aspect of a month, i.e. one 月 is a time span of 30 days.

`月份` refers to a particular point or period of time in the year.

What confuses people is they both can be used to express 'month N of the year' and are completely interchangeable in this usage. E.g. 四月 = 四月份 = April.

But to show the difference, imaging there is a festival called 'jogger's month' when everybody is supposed to keep jogging everyday during the festival. It lasts for about 30 days that's why it's called a month, but it may start at a different point of time every year. In this case, you can say: 慢跑**月**每年在不同的**月份**举行。去年是在四月(份)，今年将是在九月(份)。

For the sentence in your question, if I understand correctly, Ramadan is actually the name of a month on Islamic calendar, so both 月 and 月份 are correct. 月份 would give people slightly more hint on it's at the same time every year, while 月 merely indicates the length of the period.

Some discussions on 月 vs. 月份 as FYI.

- http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1410353&langid=22
- http://www.italki.com/question/107868